# Python print certain lines from terraform output from certain resource

Tags: python, python-3.x, terraform, output

I'm trying to print certain line, from a string that is inside a variable in python3, the variable comes from `os.popen` execution like the following example.

```
some_url = os.popen(f"terraform state show 'module.dns.aws_route53_record.main'").read()
```

In order to print the output I do something like this

```
print(f"{color.DARKCYAN}[SOME_URL]{color.END}, {some_url}")
```

But the output look's like this...

```
[SOME_URL], # module.dns.aws_route53_record.main:
resource "aws_route53_record" "main" {
    allow_overwrite = true
    fqdn            = "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com"
    id              = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.com_CNAME"
    name            = "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxx.xxxx"
    records         = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx",
    ]
    ttl             = xxxx
    type            = "xxxx"
    zone_id         = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

Is it a simple way to parse and print just the line with the `fqdn` after `[SOME_URL]` ???

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```py
import re

string = '''
resource "aws_route53_record" "main" {
    allow_overwrite = true
    fqdn            = "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com"
    id              = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.com_CNAME"
    name            = "xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xx.xxxxxx.xxxx"
    records         = [
        "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx",
    ]
    ttl             = xxxx
    type            = "xxxx"
    zone_id         = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
'''
if m := re.search("(?<=\n)\s*fqdn\s.*", string):
    fqdn = re.sub("\s+=", " =", m.group().strip())
    print(f"\x1b[1;36m[SOME_URL]\x1b[0m, {fqdn}")
```

```
[SOME_URL], fqdn = "xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com"
```

The expression should be precise enough.

I can recommend learning regular expressions especially for these cases!

> "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.'
> Now they have two problems."

> "Regular expressions tend to be easier to write than they are to read. This is less of a problem if you are the only one who ever needs to maintain the program (or sed routine, or shell script, or what have you), but if several people need to watch over it, the syntax can turn into more of a hindrance than an aid.")
> (Stephen Ramsay, University of Virginia)

Comment: Solved using re module like this ```some_var = re.search('fqdn.+=.+"(.+)"', os.popen(f"terraform state show 'module.dns.aws_route53_record.main'").read())``` and then the print `print(some_var(1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform has a very nice way to grant you access to information you need from the state in the form of [outputs values](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs). In your case, you can create an output variable for the fqdn and read just this one piece of information:

```
output "main_dns" {
  value = aws_route53_record.main.fqdn
}
```

And in the python call you use the `terraform output main_dns` command

```
some_url = os.popen(f"terraform output main_dns").read()
```

Now you can use the fqdn as you see fit.

[terraform output documentation](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/output)

Comment: Hello Totem, thanks for helping me, yeah I know how to use terraform and the outputs, but suppose that command output came from another command not terraform, I need solve this from the python side.